# "foomatic-rip failed" when printing to HP 2050

Tags: printing, lexmark

I was printing fine to an Lexmark CX310dn printer with my Ubuntu 12.04 box until a few days ago. Now when ever I print something I notice the text

> foomatic-rip failed

next to the printer name at the print dialogue.

In the CUPS control center (http://localhost:631/) I see that the driver for my printer is

> Driver:   Lexmark 2050 Foomatic/c2050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran

```
tail /var/log/cups/error_log
```

after a failed print and noticed this line a few lines before the `foomatic-rip failed` error

```
bash: c2050: command not found
```

So I tried these commands:

```
$ c2050
The program 'c2050' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-c2050

$ sudo apt-get install printer-driver-c2050
```

After this the printer started printing but was printing garbage. So I first I rebooted the printer and then I removed and re-added the printer. I did it the hard way but you can try the easy way through **System Settings** first. Anyway, in my case first I added the driver suggested on http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Lexmark/Lexmark-CX310dn. I downloaded the deb file and installed it with

```
sudo dpkg --install openprinting-ppds-postscript-lexmark_20140829-1lsb3.2_all.deb
```

and then I visited the CUPs interface and added the printer.

Case solved.